# Восстановление заменённого общего файла для двух пакетов при удалении одного из них

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, deb

Пусть есть два пакета `libfoo` и `libbar`. 
В состав каждого из них входит файл `general_file`.

Пусть пакет `libbar` зависит от пакета `libfoo` (строчка `Depends: libfoo` в `control`). При установке пакет `libbar` расширяет функционал пакета `libfoo`, заменяя его файл `general_file` своим (строчка `Replaces: libfoo` в `control`).

Я ожидал, что при удалении `libbar` восстановится `general_file` пакета `libfoo`, но файл просто удаляется.

Можно ли стандартными средствами `dpkg` осуществить восстановление исходного файла `general_file` из `libfoo` при удалении `libbar`? Или же писать вручную этот функционал в `*inst/*rm` скриптах? Возможно, подход к задаче не совсем корректен?

Уcловимся, что `diff general_file1 general_file2` стремится к бесконечности, поэтому избежим использования `awk/sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как упомянуто в [документации](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces):

> It is usually an error for a package to contain files which are on the system in another package
>
> Normally, Breaks should be used in conjunction with Replaces.

То есть это в целом неверно, что у вас есть два пакета, предоставляющих одноимённый файл. Потому поведение и может казаться странным. Обычно директива `Replaces` сопровождается меткой `Breaks`.

Обычно пакеты предоставляющие альтернативы работают через механизм [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/update-alternatives.1.en.html). Так, для примера, текстовые редакторы устанавливаются со своими собственными бинарниками, не пересекаясь с другими именами файлов. Затем через `update-alternatives` регистрируются как доступная альтернатива с общим именем - симлинком.

Comment: есть ещё и [diversions](https://wiki.debian.org/Adding%20and%20removing%20diversions)